# Formatting Bootstrap-Datetimepicker input in Rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, datetime, momentjs, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I am using [this](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) datetimepicker to get a datetime input from the user. The problem is that when my form is submitted, the datetime is in the following format (see [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) for formatting tokens):

```
MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm A
```

But rails only accepts this format:

```
YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss z
```

This causes some strange behavior in that sometimes the form accepts the datetime, but is reading the months and days around the wrong way, and only declines the form when months is more than 31 and days is more than 12.

How can I change the formatting of either the rails datetime, or the value submitted by datetimepicker, so that they are consistent and my form works correctly? I have tried adding

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
   format: 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss z'
});
```

to my datetimepicker, but this causes some error and the datetimepicker disappears from the form.